# Java elasticsearch Ngram 0 hits

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am using elasticsearch with Java, I need to find user firstname or lastname by typing only 3 chars. 
I have done normal search, when I type full firstname or lastname I will get answer.
Someone told me I shoudl use Ngram, but I was trying, and now I can find nothing.

My code :

```
TransportClient client = TransportClient.builder().build()
            .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1"), 9300));

    XContentBuilder settingsBuilder = XContentFactory.jsonBuilder()
            .startObject()
                .startObject("analysis")
                    .startObject("analyzer")
                        .startObject("ngram_analyzer")
                            .field("tokenizer", "ngram_tokenizer")
                        .endObject()
                    .endObject()
                    .startObject("tokenizer")
                        .startObject("ngram_tokenizer")
                            .field("type","nGram")
                            .field("min_gram","3")
                            .field("max_gram","8")
                        .endObject()
                    .endObject()
                .endObject()
            .endObject();

    String json = settingsBuilder.string();

client.admin().indices()
            .prepareCreate("user").setSettings(settingsBuilder).get();

    QueryBuilder qb = multiMatchQuery(
            search,
            "firstname","lastname"
    );
    SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch("user")
            .setQuery(qb)
            .execute()
            .get();

    System.out.println(response.getHits().getTotalHits()); // 0
```

I was trying to use this solution :  https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html;

And the System.out.println(json) gives me :

```
    {
  "analysis": {
    "analyzer": {
      "ngram_analyzer": {
        "tokenizer": "ngram_tokenizer"
      }
    },
    "tokenizer": {
      "ngram_tokenizer": {
        "type": "nGram",
        "min_gram": "3",
        "max_gram": "8"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So it should be correct, but as I said, 0 hits.
I have trying to copy setting to json file and load it, effect was the same.

I have spend whole day on this, I will be grateful for your help.

Comment: What test data are you indexing and what are you searching for?

Comment: Im adding data this way :
 IndexResponse response = client.prepareIndex("user", "id", Long.toString(model.getId()))
                .setSource(jsonBuilder()
                        .startObject()
                        .field("id", model.getId())
                        .field("firstname", model.getFirstname())
                        .field("lastname", model.getLastname())
                        .field("loaded", model.isContentLoaded())
                        .endObject()
                )
                .get();

Comment: And I am searching for firstname or lastname , for example "Matejko", I want to find him by just "tej".

Something like this 
http://localhost:9200/user/_search?q=lastname:*tej
is working well, but I need to use elasticsearch by Java, not links/curl.

Comment: If directly using REST api works will then obviously the issue is not with data but the query. Try using matchQuery on 1 field. Lets see if you get some data or not.

Comment: This does not work well, I am tired of this, I am using something like  "http://localhost:9200/user/_search?q=firstname:*zbi*%20OR%20lastname:*tej*", and I am getting json from the response, it works well.